# Magento 1.9 - Attach Custom image from product view page front end

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, multiple-file-upload

I am using below code to upload/attach images from product view page frontend, images uploading in directory but not save in quote item & order item table.

```
    <?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Etheme_Buyshopconfig_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (isset($_FILES['options_2_file']['name']) && $_FILES['options_2_file']['name'] != '') {

                foreach ($_FILES['options_2_file']['name'] as $key => $image) {
                    Mage::log('looping');
                    if (empty($image)) {
                        Mage::log('continue');
                        continue;
                    }
                    try {
                        Mage::log('uploading');
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader(
                                    array(
                                    'name' => $_FILES['options_2_file']['name'][$key],
                                    'type' => $_FILES['options_2_file']['type'][$key],
                                    'tmp_name' => $_FILES['options_2_file']['tmp_name'][$key],
                                    'error' => $_FILES['options_2_file']['error'][$key],
                                    'size' => $_FILES['options_2_file']['size'][$key]
                                        )
                                );

                        // Any extention would work
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_options' . DS. 'quote' . DS;
                        $img = $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['options_2_file']['name'][$key]);
                        //var_dump($img);exit;
                        //$imagepath = $img['file'];

                        //$saveData['options_2_file'] = $imagepath;

                        Mage::log($img['file']);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                    }

                }
            }

        parent::addAction();

    }
}
```

Image name/path not saved in info_buyRequest "sales_flat_quote_item_option" table and  "sales_flat_order_item".

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the product must be in `$data`.

So you get the model of the desired product :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

...//And you need to rewrite the path of the picture.

$product->save();
```

I hope that my answer will bring you closer to the solution.

Comment: @shoaib Saleem try this code

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: What is $id?Add complete code.

Comment: `$data = $this->getRequest();` and `var_dump($data) ;` $data have id products.